# Using Tooltip with Joined data on a plot

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I have some data partitioned into three sublists:

```
data = {{2776.37, 2016.64, 1483.51, 1027.35, 500.878, 94.1385, 
    310.402, 282.548, 257.886, 224.359, 218.688, 209.312, 215.776, 
    198.78}, {40.5063, 24.633, 12.069, 8.3151, 6.35135, 15.0977, 
    8.74372, 15.5125, 9.34959, 9.70696, 11.125, 12.1457, 10.8075, 
    9.7561}, {113.08, 124.633, 75.9698, 59.5186, 55.9459, 7.81528, 
    57.4372, 69.5291, 80.4878, 88.2784, 105.563, 127.935, 148.571, 
    148.78}};
```

Each sublist can be represented by a label,

```
samp = {"x", "y", "z"};
```

I want to create a `ListLogPlot` with a `Tooltip` with the sample name that appears when the mouse hovers over each subset. I have tried,

```
ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data, samp], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

but this flashes "{x,y,z}" for each subset. How do I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me you just need to add [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

```
ListLogPlot[Thread @ Tooltip[data, samp], Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {
   {2776.37, 2016.64, 1483.51, 1027.35,
    500.878, 94.1385, 310.402, 282.548,
    257.886, 224.359, 218.688, 209.312,
    215.776, 198.78},
   {40.5063, 24.633, 12.069, 8.3151,
    6.35135, 15.0977, 8.74372, 15.5125,
    9.34959, 9.70696, 11.125, 12.1457,
    10.8075, 9.7561},
   {113.08, 124.633, 75.9698, 59.5186,
    55.9459, 7.81528, 57.4372, 69.5291,
    80.4878, 88.2784, 105.563, 127.935,
    148.571, 148.78}};

samp = {"x", "y", "z"};

ListLogPlot[
 Tooltip @@@ Transpose[{data, samp}],
 Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

Well I just used your previous question to get this working. You cannot just wrap evrything in ToolTip - you need to wrap each data set in it with its specific label:

```
ListLogPlot[
  MapThread[
   Tooltip, {data, 
    Style[#, 15, Bold, FontFamily -> "Georgia"] & /@ {"Sample X", 
      "Sample Y", "Sample Z"}}], Joined -> True, 
  Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[14], xaxis}], Automatic}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, GridLines -> {Range[14], Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.015], Opacity[.5]]] // Magnify
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice :) Sorry for the repetitive example but I needed to know both answers and I thought it would be clumsy to put them in one question...

Comment: @geordie I understand. I am not sure what moderators would advise. I personally would still put it in the same question, saying I need 1) x-labels 2) ToolTips - because basically you joining all this in one single object correct?

Comment: I guess the issue is that people who are searching for answers to their burning questions might miss one or the other solution if the question title doesn't explicitly describe both.

Comment: @geordie I see your point. BTW did you look through the site for similar questions? I feel like similar things were asked before.

Comment: I tried.. this is always one of the issues with searching for existing answers. A lot of questions don't have a very descriptive title and may not be cataloged properly. It can be quite difficult for a casual SE user to know whether or not their particular question is a duplicate.

Comment: Why not use `TooltipStyle` instead of mapping the tooltips onto `Style`. Would be cleaner I think.